# How to know the android textview is set with a text

Tags: android, textview

Is there any callback is invoked if an android textview is set with a text

Comment: What are you trying for? Explain it briefly?

Comment: just for you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: I have to set an image based on the text that user types on the textview.But how can I know when the textview is set

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add a `TextWatcher` to a TextView for watching text changes in TextView as:

```
TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview);
    textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

             //here you will get changed text in textview
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is:

```
if( TextView.getText().length() != 0) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if your TextView has any text using the following:

```
TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
if(yourTextview.getText().toString().equals(""))
     //it is blank
else
     //it has text
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this in my opinion is:

```
if(TextView.getText == null);
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The only way to tell at runtime if user has set text from code is to create an instance

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_id)
```

and check if this text has text with `getText()` method and see if your initially textView has text.